# Scrolling div boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to implement a strip of scrolling div boxes in a horizontal line which spans in full width of the browser.

```
<style>
.block_box{min-height:300px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:400px;}
.block{ float:left; width:200;height:300px;background:grey;margin:10px;padding:20px;}</style>

<div class="block_box">
                <div class="block">1</div>
                <div class="block">2</div>
                <div class="block">3</div>
                <div class="block">4</div>
                <div class="block">5</div>
                <div class="block">6</div>
                <div class="block">7</div>
                <div class="block">8</div>
            </div>
```

I tried but after 4 or 5 block it is not hiding behind the browser instead it brakes to a new line

Comment: can you elaborate your question?? Didnt get what you are trying to ask??

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283038/make-div-expand-only-horizontally-when-more-floating-divs-are-added-to-it

Comment: Not yet, I want  a div strip which will have a scroll button on left and right. This strip will contain more than 5 boxes. just like a image strip which spans full width and the more thumbnails hidden behind the container

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS add `display:inline` and `white-space:nowrap;`

```
.block_box{min-height:300px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:400px;}
.block{ float:left; display:inline; white-space:nowrap; width:200;height:300px;background:grey;margin:10px;padding:20px;}
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) is about white-space. [More detailed explanation](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with a demo of what you want:

http://jsbin.com/anekos/1/edit

New CSS:

```
.block_box{ height:320px; width:100%; overflow:auto;top:100px;}
.block{display: table-cell; min-width:200px;height:300px;background:grey;margin:10px;padding:20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages for the width of each block so it will fit the width of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width on the div with the class of "block_box"

Answer (score 0):

try applying `overflow-x: scroll;` css style to your .block_box div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an outer div with fixed width. And then use   `overflow-x:auto` property like this

**HTML Code :**

```
<div class="outer_div">
    <div class="block_box">
                <div class="block">1</div>
                <div class="block">2</div>
                <div class="block">3</div>
                <div class="block">4</div>
                <div class="block">5</div>
                <div class="block">6</div>
                <div class="block">7</div>

     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.block_box{height:200px;width:800px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:400px;}
.block{ float:left; width:100;height:200px;background:grey;margin:10px;padding:20px;}
.outer_div{ width: 500px; overflow-x:auto;}
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/AQr6h/2/